# Model comparison on different datasets + Non-nested model comparison

Tags: r, logistic, anova, subset

I actually have two questions. Similar questions unfortunatelly do not answer mine.

1)I realize that with `anova(model1,model2)` one can only compare two models if they are based on the same dataset. Are there any methods to compare two models based on different datasets if one dataset is a subset of another one, but there is an extra predictor in the bigger dataset? Smaller dataset contains only two-element items, and bigger one contains both two- and three-element items plus a predictor column to distinguish between two- and three-element items.

2)It looks like one can only compare two models with `anova(model1,model2)`  if they are nested. Firstly, I have a hard time finding an "oficical" confirmation (documentation, paper, some statistics book), do you have anything in mind? Secondly, I want to compare two logistic regression models that differ in one predictor: `DV ~ A + B + X`  vs  `DV ~ A + B + Y`. X and Y measure the same thing (simple difference between two elements), but uses differenet scales for the elements. Is AIC my only option?

Comment: Why do you want to compare these models? What is your actual goal?

Comment: @Roland thank you for the comment! In the first problem I would like to know whether the same predictors will stay relevant for the bigger dataset, whetherr 2 and 3 element items differ; and in the second problem I want to know which predictor is the best one X or Y.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are attempting to use ANOVA / likelihood ratio tests. re 1. I'm not sure but it seems like you actual want cross-validation? Or is this some kind of sensitivity analysis? re 2. So, you are interested in predictive performance? Split your data in a training and a test dataset and test predictive performance.